# Formal name for $n \bmod 2$ group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Apologies for how basic this question is, but what is the name of the group containing the elements $\{0,1\}$ with an operation of $n \bmod 2$? I tried finding the answer on the wiki list of groups, but I couldn’t find it.

Comment: The group of integers modulo two.

Comment: As for the symbol, $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ (or, with less consensus, $\Bbb Z_2$).

Comment: more abstractly, it might be called $C_2$, which is the (unique, cyclic) group with two elements.

Comment: "You tried finding the answer on the wiki list of groups, but you couldn’t find it"? Really? But on the [wiki list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups) $\Bbb Z_n$ is explained. So take $n=2$. Or look into the list for $n=2$.

Comment: The [finite simple group of order two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BipvGD-LCjU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_2$
(I need to add some more characters for this answer to be submitted.)